# Incorrect File Path When Using dotnet xunit.console.dll

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit

I have a `.NET Core` multitargeting application that is using `xunit.runner.console` to run unit tests.  When my tests look on disk for a file, it fails to find them when running `xunit.runner.console` against the `netcoreapp2.0` test assemblies but succeeds when running against `net452` assemblies.

**Failing Command (netcoreapp2.0)**

`dotnet repo\src\packages\xunit.runner.console.2.3.0\tools\netcoreapp2.0\xunit.console.dll repo\bld\bin\{project}\AnyCPU_Release\netcoreapp2.0\{projectName}.dll`

**Resulting File Path**

`repo\TestFiles\`

**Expected File Path**

`repo\bld\bin\{project}\AnyCPU_Release\netcoreapp2.0\TestFiles\`

**Successful Command (net452)**

`repo\src\packages\xunit.runner.console.2.3.0\tools\net452\xunit.console.exe repo\bld\bin\{project}\AnyCPU_Release\net452\{projectName}.dll`

**Code to Find Files**

`var files = Directory.GetFiles($"TestFiles");`